# Convergence of simple improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration

My task is to settle whether or not the improper integral
$$\int_{0}^{e} \frac{\sin{\log{x}}}{x} \mbox{d}x $$
converges. I know it's easy, but since I'm new to improper integrals I ask for your help.
I tried by substituting: $t = \log{x}$

$$\frac{\mbox{d}x}{x} = \mbox{d}t$$

$x$ is from $0$ to $e$, so $t$ is from $- \infty $ to $1$, so I'm left with integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} \sin{t}\, \mbox{d}t$$
which diverges. Is this correct? If not - please, show me how it's done.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.